# Typography & wordpress

Tags: wordpress, typography

I wonder if its possible to control the typography when using wordpress? For example, if a word doesn't fit in the row, it gets hyphenated and doesn't jump to the other row.
The customer I am doing a website for wants the words that doesn't fit in the row to get hyphenated.

Update:

```
p { hyphens: auto;  margin-bottom:24px; font-family:candara,arial,sans-serif; color: #000000; font-weight: 300; }
```

The hyphens: auto;, didnt work

Comment: I tried that, didnt work

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have tried something along these lines already, but [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/) gives a more thorough explanation of how the hyphens property is language-dependent. Different languages have different default behaviors for hyphens. Also browser support for the hyphens property is [a little spotty](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/#browser-support), with Chrome only supporting the "none" value.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good answer to this question here:
https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/

```
.hyphenate {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```